# Step by Step Explanation of Sigmod odds function

Tags: proof-explanation, exponential-function, machine-learning

I am pursuing a Machine Learning Course but my poor maths basics are really bottlenecking the progress.

$$p = \frac1{1+e^{-(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x)}}$$

$$1-p = \frac{e^{-(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x)}}{1+e^{-(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x)}}$$

$$\frac{p}{1-p}= e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x}$$

I am trying to understand this derivation step by step. Can someone please me the transition from equation 1 to equation 3?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry about that, I am new to the platform. Will follow the same in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you let $z=e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x}$, your task is to solve for $z$ in

$$p=\frac{1}{1+e^{-(\beta_0+\beta_1x)}}=\frac1{1+z^{-1}}$$

Then we have

$$1+z^{-1}=\frac1p$$

Can you  try to solve for $z$? Try to solve for  $z^{-1}$ first.